# Displaying information from a specific id from a while loop on a different page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I created an admin function to be able to display/add/edit products that are on my site. I am having no issues with adding and fetching/displaying what products are on my site.

Being able to see the current product I am trying to edit is where I am having difficulties. I am displaying the products that are in my database by fetching all of them through a while loop. I added an edit link that goes to editproducts.php.

The problem I am having is I am not sure how to get the product's data that I clicked on to display and fetch just that product_id's data.

The way I display all of the products

```
<table class="tableproduct">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="thproduct">Product ID</th>
                            <th class="thproduct">Product Name</th>
                            <th class="thproduct">Price</th>
                            <th class="thproduct">Category</th>
                            <th class="thproduct">Description</th>
                            <th class="thproduct"></th>
                            <th class="thproduct"></th>
                        </tr>   
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['product_id']) && is_numeric($_POST['product_id'])) {
       mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM products WHERE product_id = ". $_POST['product_id'] ."")
       or die("Could not DELETE: " . mysqli_error($con)); 
       "Your product was successfully deleted."; 
}   else {Session::flash('addproduct', 'Your product was successfully deleted.');
}


if( $result ){  
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) :
?>
                         <form method="POST" action="adminproducts.php">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['product_id']; ?> </td>
                                <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['name']; ?> </td> 
                                <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['price']; ?> </td>
                                <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['category']; ?> </td>
                                <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['description']; ?> </td>
                                <td class="tdproduct"><a href='editproducts.php?product_id=<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>'>EDIT</a></td>
                                <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<? echo $row['product_id']; ?>"/>
                                <td class="tdproduct"><input name="delete" type="submit" value="DELETE "/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </form>
<?php   
        endwhile; 
        }
?>
                        </table>
```

The page where I want to edit the product.

I tried the GET function and pulling the product_id. This does nothing. The name and price that I am trying to echo at the bottom of the code does not display anything other than the echoed string '$'.

```
<?php
$_GET['product_id'];
?>
                <form action="" method="post">
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="product_id">Product ID</label>
                            <input type="text" name="product_id" class="inputbar">
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="name">Product Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="price">Price</label>
                            <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="price">
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="category">Category</label>
                            <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="category">
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="description">Description</label>
                            <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="description">
                        </div>  

                            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
                            <label for="signinButton">
                                <input type="submit" id="signinButton" value="Update">
                            </label>
                </form>

                            <p><?php echo "<a href='./viewProduct.php?view_product=$id'>" . $product['name'] . "</a>"; ?></p>
                            <p> <?php echo "$" . $product['price']; ?> </p>
```

Is there something I'm not doing correctly or over-looking?

Comment: you specify `form method="POST"`. your form variables will be contained in `$_POST`, or `$_REQUEST`, but not `$_GET`.  Also, you should probably never delete a product from the database - have a 'deleted' flag, sure, and set that, but never remove it completely.

Comment: I changed my editproducts.php page to $_POST and it still isn't grabbing the data from the page before

Comment: you actually have to do something with the variable -- just putting `$_POST['product_id']` isnt going to do anything without you using it somehow -- looking up the id in a database, echoing it out to the document etc

Comment: Right, this is the part I am confused on how to do with the specific product I selected.

Comment: same way you delete it? just select the info instead.